# Are positive matrices always hyperbolic?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I was simply wondering the following:

If a matrix $A \in \text{SL}_n(\mathbb R)$ has determinant one and all entries positive, is it *hyperbolic*?

(By *hyperbolic*, I mean no eigenvalue of $A$ lies on the unit circle, i.e.

$$Av = \lambda v\quad\text{for }v\neq 0 \stackrel?\implies |\lambda|\neq 1.\text)$$

---

I would think this is the case, since one immediately has
$$A(\{x \in \mathbb  R^n :\, x_i\geq 0 \text{ for each }i\}) \subset \{x \in \mathbb R \,:\, x_i>0\text{ for each }i\},$$

which seems to give rise to an "expanding cone" in the sense of uniformly hyperbolic dynamics. But I'm wondering how close is this to an actual proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Random counterexample:
$$
P=\pmatrix{3&-1&1\\ 2&1&1\\ 1&0&-1},
\ D=\pmatrix{\frac98\\ &1\\ &&\frac89},
\ A=PDP^{-1}=\pmatrix{1.037698&0.037698&0.186508\\ 0.019841&1.019841&0.150794\\ 0.033730&0.033730&0.956349}.
$$